# how to create an editable input on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a page that I want to use to allow users to see what in currently in the database and edit them by clicking on the box.
I have a pretty hacky method that works for text imputs but for a drop down box or date selector completely falls apart.
my HTML

```
   <td name='joineddate133'>
    <input type='date'
    id='joind133'
    name='joinda133
    value='2012-03-15'
    class='toedit'
    readonly='readonly'
    onclick='enablejoindate(this.id)'
    size='20'   />
    < /td>
```

The current Javascript

```
<script>
function enablejoindate(joindatid){
    $(function(){ 
    $("input:text[id="+ joindatid +"]").removeAttr("class");
    $("input:text[id="+ joindatid +"]").removeAttr("readonly");
    $("input:text[id="+ joindatid +"]").addClass("inlineditjoind");
  });
  }
  </script>
```

The inlinedit class is used as a marker so the jquery can find it easily to post and the toedit class currently just hides the attributes.

Obviously this solution isn't great and I would like to try and work out a better way to maybe create an input on the double click function etc.

Comment: With a dropdown, how do you envisage a user would add a new menu item?

Comment: I was thinking it would just exist in place of the text, so it goes from looking like just text to being an input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have all fields as readonly and hidden until focussed:

```
$("table").on("focus", "input, select", function(){
    $(this)
    .prop("readonly", false)
    .removeClass("toedit");
});

$("table").on("blur", "input, select", function(){
    $(this)
    .prop("readonly", true)
    .addClass("toedit")
    .siblings("span").text($(this).val());
});

$("table").on("click", "td", function(){
    $(this).children().focus();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CyN2V/3/) (**updated again**)

Comment: That is literally exactly what I was trying to do, it's the closest in style to the goal I hoped to achieve.

Comment: I've updated the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CyN2V/3/) again to set the content of the `<td>` after a field has been updated.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, I couldn't get past the bit where mine was ugly and broken though!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery, use a jQuery event. It's best to set `readonly` to false with the `prop()` method:

```
$('input[type=date]').on('click', function(){
    $(this)
      .removeClass("toedit")
      .prop("readonly", false)
      .addClass("inlineditjoind");    
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LPNcH/2/)

Comment: thanks for the info on prop, why is it prop and not addClass is it just a jquery thing?

Comment: A [class](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) and a [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (property) are two different things.

Comment: ah, that's my noobishness showing, probably ought to read a textbook or two

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [X-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/).

```
<a
  href="#"
  id="joinda133"
  data-type="date"
  data-viewformat="dd.mm.yyyy"
  data-pk="1"
  data-placement="right"
  data-original-title="Date you've joined"
>25.02.2013</a>
```

Comment: that seems really effective, but I would have to change loads of other functions that are associated with my code to use it. I'll bear it in mind next time need to do something like this, programming with it in mind from the beginning would probably save me time.

Answer (score 1):

**[Have a look to the DEMO <kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3m6Vw/)**

**JS/JQUERY -**

```
$("#joind133").on('click',function(){
    $(this).removeProp("readonly")
        .removeClass("toedit")
        .addClass("inlineditjoind");
});
```

**HTML -**

```
<td name='joineddate133'>
    <input type='date' id='joind133' name='joinda133' value='2012-03-15' class='toedit' readonly='readonly' size='20'/>
</td>
```

**UPDATE ON REQUEST FOR MAKING IT GENERIC BINDING**

```
$("input[type='date']").on('click',function(){
    $(this).removeProp("readonly")
        .removeClass("toedit")
        .addClass("inlineditjoind");
});
```

Comment: that is much cleaner than my code. I am still adjusting to the way to write properly formed jquery

Comment: the most important change was using prop instead of attr for readonly

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I generate the id's based on what is in the database, so there are 100+ date attributes with different ids created on run time. I need a method to run on a generic date attribute that can be called on any clicked date, if you see what I mean